# Проблема при выборке данных из таблицы

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть два класса, которые описывают таблицы. В Классе DAO создал метод, который выбирает данные о пациенте, по введенным параметрам. До того как добавил в классы отношение OneToMany и ManyToOne все работало. Сейчас выдает ошибку:

> Исключение: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping
> for entity: mis.models.Police column: patientID (should be mapped with
> insert="false" update="false")

Как это исправить?

Класс Patient

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "fam")
    private String fam;
    @Column(name = "im")
    private String im;
    @Column(name = "ot")
    private String ot;
    @Column(name = "bdate")
    private Date bdate;
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private int sex;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "mail")
    private String mail;
    @Column(name = "snils")
    private String snils;
    @Column(name = "createdate")
    private Date createdate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private List<Police> policeList;

    public List<Police> getPoliceList() {
        return policeList;
    }

    public void setPoliceList(List<Police> policeList) {
        this.policeList = policeList;
    }

    public Patient() {

    }

    public Patient(String fam, String im, String ot, Date bdate, int sex, String phone, String mail, String snils, Date createdate) {
        this.fam = fam;
        this.im = im;
        this.ot = ot;
        this.bdate = bdate;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.snils = snils;
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFam() {
        return fam;
    }

    public void setFam(String fam) {
        this.fam = fam;
    }

    public String getIm() {
        return im;
    }

    public void setIm(String im) {
        this.im = im;
    }

    public String getOt() {
        return ot;
    }

    public void setOt(String ot) {
        this.ot = ot;
    }

    public Date getBdate() {
        return bdate;
    }

    public void setBdate(Date bdate) {
        this.bdate = bdate;
    }

    public int getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(int sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getSnils() {
        return snils;
    }

    public void setSnils(String snils) {
        this.snils = snils;
    }

    public Date getCreatedate() {
        return createdate;
    }

    public void setCreatedate(Date createdate) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }
}
```

Класс Police

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "police")
public class Police {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "createdate")
    private Date createdate;

    @Column(name = "patientID")
    private int patientID;

    @Column(name = "ser")
    private String ser;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "orgID")
    private int orgID;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "patientID")
    private Patient patient;

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }

    public Police() {

    }

    public Police(Date createdate, int patientID, String ser, String code, int orgID, int status) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
        this.patientID = patientID;
        this.ser = ser;
        this.code = code;
        this.orgID = orgID;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedate() {
        return createdate;
    }

    public void setCreatedate(Date createdate) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
    }

    public int getPatientID() {
        return patientID;
    }

    public void setPatientID(int patientID) {
        this.patientID = patientID;
    }

    public String getSer() {
        return ser;
    }

    public void setSer(String ser) {
        this.ser = ser;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getOrgID() {
        return orgID;
    }

    public void setOrgID(int orgID) {
        this.orgID = orgID;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Класс DAO

```
public class PatientDao {

    public List<Patient> findPatientsWithParams(Integer id, String fam, String im, String ot) {
        List<Patient> list = (List<Patient>) HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession().
                createQuery("FROM Patient where (id = :id or :id is null) and (fam like :fam or :fam is null) and (im like :im or :im is null) and (ot like :ot or :ot is null)").
                setParameter("id", id).
                setParameter("fam", fam + "%").
                setParameter("im", im + "%").
                setParameter("ot", ot + "%").
                list();

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Column(name = "patientID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int patientID; Решил проблему прописав следующее, но не понял почему проблема ушла. Можете объяснить кто-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдельно колонку для `private int patientID` для Hibernate не нужно описывать, т.е.  поле это не нужно, т.к. уже есть `private Patient patient;` - о чем в ошибке и говорится. Добавление параметров приводит к тому, что при вставке/обновлении Hibernate будет игнорировать это поле.

Hibernate нужен, чтобы в своем коде работать с объектами и отношениями между объектами. Все знание о реальных таблицах (первичные ключи, внешние ключи) заканчивается правильным маппингом в Entity классах. (Но не нужно это понимать абсолютно, в реальных проектах ситуации бывают разные)

Comment: Хмм.. А как тогда добавить новый полис в таблицу police? Точнее как передать patientID при вставке записи в таблицу police?

Comment: police.setPatient(patient) - остальное делает hibernate

Comment: не очень понял. Я создал метод для вставки полиса     public void savePolice(Police police) {
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(police);
        tx1.commit();
        session.close();
    }. В контроллере вызываю так: dao.savePolice(new Police(new Date(),  "888", "4444444455555555", 1, 1)); но я сюда не передаю id пациента не пойму как теперь это сделать

Comment: Сделать метод в PatienDao, который вернет Patient по его id (что-то типа ...openSession().get(Patient.class, id);), и засетать его в  Police/передать в конструкторе, как с id только уже объект.

Comment: А можно пример привести? Я что-то не могу понять. Есть метод, который возвращает пациента по его id     public Patient findByID(int id) {
        return HibernateSessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession().get(Patient.class, id);
    }

Comment: Так?     public Police(Date createdate, Patient patient, String ser, String code, int org_id, int status) {
        this.createdate = createdate;
        this.setPatient(patient);
        this.ser = ser;
        this.code = code;
        this.org_id = org_id;
        this.status = status;
    }

Comment: Можете пояснить как это работает? Вроде получилось но мало что понял как это отработало.

Comment: Hibernate сам делает все магию, для этого и нужны аннотации типа Id и OneToMany и др.

Comment: Понимаю) Но более подробно в моем примере как Hibernate понимает что когда я передаю объект пациента, в поле patientID нужно поставить его id? с jdbc попроще конечно, правда кода больше, но там понятно что как происходит, а hibernate пока для меня темный лес